# Send push-notification to native Android SDK used by another app

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, android-sdk-2.1

Is there any way to use push notification inside an Android SDK which is run inside another app.

So the thing is.. we are offering a client service in Android SDK that we are developing. The client app will use our native android sdk inside their cordova app.

Is there any way for our backend system to send push notification to the SDK ?

Comment: well, if I got your question, then it is done same way as for your app. You have to declare service (your SDK's users actually have to) in the manifest, etc.

Comment: So I can send að push notification to the ID of my android SDK (manifest.xml file) which is running inside the cordova app and the push notification can be seen in the cordova app  ?